# rsync - report only synced folders in verbose output

Tags: rsync

```
rsync -av -n source_dir target_dir
```

shows files to be synced.
Can rsync verbose output summarize which inner folders only of *source dir* are going to be synced in *target_dir*?

Comment: Folders have a trailing / in the output.  So if you grep for it by adding "| grep -E '/$'"  Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Robert Leckie

```
rsync -av -n source_dir target_dir | grep --color  -E '^([a-z]+/){2}$'
```

achieved what's needed